# Body media query doesn't work

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a navigation bar which has padding to allow content to display under the navigation bar. For mobiles I want to lessen the padding but the media query doesn't seem to work. Any ideas to why?

Example:

```css
body{
  padding-top: 70px; 
}
p.t{
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .body {
        padding-top: 0px;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
<p class="t">
This is my pretend navbar woo.
</p>
<p>
hello
</p>
</body>
```

Comment: add wrapper element and put there that margin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing `.body` instead of `body`. By using `.body`, the CSS is searching for an element with [`class="body"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors), instead of an element [`<body>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors). Simple fix:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    body {
        padding-top: 0;
    }
}
```